# Reference to (module only) global function within a class method

Tags: python, function-pointers, encapsulation

In python one can easily refer to a global method by means of it's name.

```
def globalfoo(a):
    print(a)


class myClass:
    def test(self):
        v = globalfoo
        v("hey")

t = myClass()
t.test()
```

Now in python one can also "hide" a (class) method by prefixing it with two underscores. - And I thought(!) one could do the same for global functions - to make a global function module-only. (Similar to C++ where one can decide to put a function declaration not in the header so it's only visible to the current compilation unit).

I then tried to combine this:

```
def __globalfoo(a):
    print(a)


class myClass:
    def test(self):
        v = __globalfoo
        v("hey")

t = myClass()
t.test()
```

However this doesn't seem to work, an error is thrown that "_myCLass__globalfoo" is undefined. So how would I make both things work: having a reference to a function. And hiding the function from the external scope?
Is a static method in this case the only/best solution?

Comment: why dont just define that function inside the class?

Comment: yes, `@staticmethod` is a nice and clean solution.

Comment: @DanielSanchez because the function doesn't *need* anything from the class. Nor is it particularly coupled with the class. And it might be a useful utility function for other classes too. But it's too specific to make it public: it's basically a very much worked out mathematical equation that's solved partially.

Comment: @paul23 but if this function will be used by multiple classes why would you do it private?

Comment: You cannot hide the function from other modules, so I think your question is moot.

Comment: Prefix it with a single underscore instead. It will work as you expect, then - while the single underscore is a convention known by any Python programmer who knows anything that this method shouldn't be touched by code outside that module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And I thought(!) one could do the same for global functions - to make a global function module-only.

You were incorrect.  Using a double-underscore name for a module-level function will not prevent it from being used in other modules.  Someone can still do `import yourmodule` and then call `yourmodule.__globalfoo`.

The double-underscore name mangling behavior is defined in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references):

> Any identifier of the form `__spam` (at least two leading underscores, at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with `_classname__spam`, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped. This mangling is done without regard to the syntactic position of the identifier, as long as it occurs within the definition of a class.

It is purely a textual substitution and takes no account of what (if anything) the double-underscore name refers to.  It just takes any identifier occurring anywhere inside the class definition that looks like `__blah` and changes it to `_class__blah`.  It is specific to class definitions and does not occur for module-level functions.

The best thing to do is prefix your function with a single underscore and document that it is not part of the public API and users of the module should not rely on it.  There is nothing to be gained by attempting to "enforce" this privacy.

Comment: Hmm makes me wonder if I should go static methods or not now. (Background I'm writing an orbital mechanics simulation. Part of it is solving kepler's equation: M = E + ecc * sin(E) for "E". Which can't be done algebraically. The best numerical methods need a first & second order derivative (as function pointer). So I'm providing this set.

Comment: @paul23: I added a little to my answer.  What you should do is name it with a single underscore and document that it's not part of the public API and people shouldn't use it.  Trying to enforce that protection is futile.

Answer (score 0):

In python, generally, we don't try that hard to make things inaccessible for other things. We trust other developers' not to modify and access things they shouldn't. Anyway, the way the language works it is almost impossible to make those things completely inaccessible.

What you can do is two things. The standard sign of internal functions in modules is a single underscore - and other programmers should know not to meddle with those functions. Python even supports that convention in some aspect - when importing like this:

```
from module import *
```

this won't import underscore-prefixed names.

The other way would be to `del method` at the end of the module. Not very conventional, but if you must it achieves what you want to do:

```
def func():
    pass
...
...
del func
```